# How to use ASP.NET validation controls in generic handlers (.ashx)?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, validation, ashx

I am using jQuery AJAX to submit a form and to make client-side validation.
Is it possible (and how) to use ASP.NET 4.5 Validation Controls when AJAX request is handled by the generic handler (.ashx) instead of web form (.aspx)?

Here is some code to make my question more clear. I would like to be able to do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" 

Inherits="Test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="text" id="Name1" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="validateName1" ControlToValidate="Name1"  OnServerValidate="Name1_ServerValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
<br /> 
        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" style="width: 195px;" />
<br /> 
        <input type="button" id="btnSendEmail" value="Send" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
            url: "TestAjaxHandler.ashx",
            type: "POST",
            ...
        })
```

**TestAjaxHandler.ashx**

```
public class TestAjaxHandler : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

}

protected void Name1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args {
    // Here goes validation logic
} 

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Maybe is good to give us some code/example to work with.

Comment: I think i'ts tight to a normal postback, u cannot do it when using jquery ajax I think.

Answer (score 0):

You "cannot" do this using CustomValidator because it's ClientValidationFunction doesn't support AJAX. jQuery supports creating a synchronous request (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings async) but in most cases you don't want to do that.

I think that best options for you would be writing your own validation control or using jQuery validation plugin with validation attributes for the server validation.